# Twitter User Stream

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am investigating using the streaming APIs to get mentions/DMs of lots of accounts. The accounts I wish to follow are going to be dynamic. Right now, I am using the twitter npm module, creating an instance of it using my consumer key/secret and access token/secret. This has allowed me to get the data I wish for the dummy account (outside of DMs which I'm not really sure how to go about getting).

Am I allowed to open up a user stream API per account I wish to follow? (Documentation on this confused me a little bit). Originally, it looked like I wanted to use Site Streams, but I don't think that is a viable option as it is in closed beta still.

As far as the DMs go, I've set my application as Read, write, and DM. Can I not access my dummy accounts DMs by using the access tokens alone? Do I need to go through the web oauth flow instead of just passing all of this data into the Twitter construct?

Thanks!